# An i-adjective immediately before 「ください」?

Tags: syntax, i-adjectives

Does it make sense to have an i-adjective (in て-form) immediately before 「ください」?

For example, when asked to choose between hot and cold coffee, can I use 「温かくてください」, or must I turn it into nominal phrase (温かいのをください)?

Another example, is it fine to say 「優しくてください」, or must I insert a て-verb before ください (優しくしてください)?

Comment: My 100th question! Woohoo ... >___<

Comment: How do you give someone a warm or a gentle?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm guessing that the て-form of i-adjective kinda changes it into a gerund, just like how て-form of verb fits before ください.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Japanese, you always need a main verb to complete a sentence. If you directly attach an i-adjective to an auxiliary `ください` via `て`, then you will not have a main verb anywhere. You need at least one main verb in between:

> 温かくしてください
>   優しくしてください

In sentences with i-adjectives or copula, it may not be obvious that you are using a verb, but underlyingly, you do have a verb. For example, the ordinary ending of an i-adjective is `い`:

> 寒い

This `い` includes a hidden verb `ある`, which is not obvious because the sequence `くある` is contracted to `い`. If you place something that interrupts the whole hidden sequence, thereby preventing the contraction, then you can see that there is indeed a hidden `ある`:

> 部屋は暗いだけでなく、寒くもある。
>   × 部屋は暗いだけでなく、寒くもい。
>   × 部屋は暗いだけでなく、寒いも。

With nouns or na-adjectives, you may end a sentence with `だ`, but that is a contracted form of `である`, which includes the verb `ある`. Again, it may not be obvious that `だ` is the contracted form of `である`, but if you place something that interrupts the whole hidden sequence and prevents the contraction, you can see that there is indeed a hidden `ある`:

> 彼は生徒でもある
>   × 彼は生徒もだ
>   × 彼は生徒だも

Comment: But I can say 「これをください」, so doesn't the ください qualify as a main verb in 「温かくてください」?

Comment: @Lukman If you are using `ください` as a main verb, then the object has to be a noun phrase. Note that they mean different things. Auxiliary ください: 'please' (do something), Main verb ください: 'please give' (something).

Comment: Regarding い being contracted form of くある, does that mean 寒くて is contraction of 寒くあって? If that's the case, doesn't the hidden あって qualify as a main verb? Or must it be explicit before auxiliary ください?

Comment: @Lukman No. 寒くて is simply 寒く + て.