# Concept of Negative Form of Auxiliary Verbs

Tags: meaning, verbs, grammar, auxiliaries

I was studying different auxiliaries and I am having a hard time understanding those auxiliaries which have their meanings attached with them.

Following the those auxiliaries and questions:

1. てみる - Its negative form is てみない. We know that it has a meaning "try" attached with it e.g. 食べてみる eat (to see what it is like). So for this my question is, when we use the negative form of てみる will the concept of "to try to see what it is like" be attached with it as well. E.g. will 食べてみない mean do not eat (to see what it feels like), or something else?
2. てあげる/てくれる - Its negative form is てあげない/てくれない.  We know that, this auxiliary has a meaning showing helpfulness and gratitude, i.e. done something for someone as a favour. E.g.　お母さんは私へ食べ物を作ってくれる means mother cooked food for me (I am thankful to her). Now, if we use the negative form てくれない, will it mean, I am thankful/grateful to her that an act was not done. E.g.　お母さんは私へってくれない, will this mean I am thankful/grateful to my mom that she did not scold me, or something else?
3. ておく - Its negative form is ておかない. We know that this auxiliary means Did something in advance or rather prepared in advance for something. E.g. 私は食べておいた, I ate (in advance for something). Now, if we use the negative form ておきなかった, will it mean I did not do this for something in future. E.g. 私は食べてなかった, will this mean I did not eat (in advance, e.g. I will ride a roller-coaster later). or something else?

教えてきださい！

Comment: You talk about secondary meanings but don't say what you think the primary meanings are. I feel that your definitions of secondary meaning are what I would call the primary meanings. Perhaps you could add a little more explanation.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the post. I wanted to mean those auxiliary verbs gave an additional meaning to the main verb

Comment: Does your textbook really call these verbs *auxiliary verbs*? They are often called [*subsidiary verbs*](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18952/5010) because *auxiliary* often refers to [something different](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/63365/5010).

Comment: Ooohh... I did not know that, I have three books in which it was written auxiliary, that's why I used the word! Thanks for telling me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add "did not", "does not", etc., and that's it.

- 食べてみる: try eating it
- 食べてみない: does not to try eating it (rather than "to try not to eat")
- 食べ物を作ってくれる: make food (for me)
- 食べ物を作ってくれない: does not make food (for me)
- 食べておく: eat in advance
- 食べておかない: does not eat in advance

お母さんは私をってくれない means something odd like "She doesn't scold me (although I want to be scolded)". "I am thankful to my mom that she did not scold me" is お母さんは私を叱らないでいてくれる. (See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3228/5010) for ないでいる)

Comment: ありがとう、 ナルトさん! I got it !

Comment: Just a doubt, does this 食べ物を食べてくれない will have an additional meaning that "I wasn't helped"?

Comment: @APK 食べてくれない means "He/she won't eat food (although I want him/her to)".

Comment: So, will ておかない, also mean that he should have gone in advance (although he did not) and and てみない mean that, he should have tried it (although he did not) ?

Comment: @APK No. てくれる implies the action is beneficial to the speaker, but the other two has nothing to do with such an implication.