# What's difference between うるさくないでください and うるさくしないでください

Tags: conjugations, negation, i-adjectives, imperatives

Don't both of them mean "Please do not be loud"?

What's the うるさく? 
Is it うるさい and change い into く to make it a noun?
Could you guys suggest the topic that I can look into and study more about them?

Thank you so much.

Comment: I think only うるさく**し**ないでください is correct. Maybe a duplicate of this link, but I find the explanation confusing: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3212/an-i-adjective-immediately-before-%e3%81%8f%e3%81%a0%e3%81%95%e3%81%84

Comment: You can think of the former as "Please don't loud" and the latter as "Please don't be loud"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

うるさくしないでください is the only correct choice. うるさくないでください is just plain ungrammatical because it lacks a verb.

～ないでください ("Please don't ～") of course needs a **verb** before it, and in this case, the verb is する (in its nai-form, し(ない)). うるさく is the adverbial form (aka "ku-form") of the i-adjective うるさい. うるさく is **adverbially** modifying する.